# How to change date format variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

i hope you can help me,  i have this code on datepicker:
EDIT: the full code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#entrada").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        var selectedDate = new Date(selected);
        var dateMin = new Date(selectedDate);
        var daystoAdd = 1;
        dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + daystoAdd); 
        var dd = dateMin.getDate();
        var mm = dateMin.getMonth() + 1;
        var y = dateMin.getFullYear();
        var dateMinFormatted = mm + '/'+ dd + '/'+ y;
        $("#salida").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateMinFormatted)
    }
}).datepicker('setDate', 'today');//dia de inicio, default HOY
$("#salida").datepicker({
    firstDay: 1,
    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'],
    weekHeader: 'Sm',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function (selected) {
        $("#entrada").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
});
```

});

i have this problem, i need the date like this "dd-mm-yy" but in the var function i cant change the "/" to "-" cause the datepicker writes a "2020" year and gets wacky. Its only this, change the dateminformatted

**if you see when i pick the "entrada" date the "salida" show the next day and block the "before" dates, thats why i cannot change the variable**

this is the demo page: www.chileansoftware.cl/cambiaso/prueba/index.asp

cheers!!!

Comment: you want a format to display, and another format to submit, is that it?

Comment: What if you just try this:  $("#salida").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });

Comment: Maybe you could check http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats . E.g. $("#salida").datepicker("option","dateFormat","dd-mm-yy");

Comment: If you want to restrict a month maybe you can use something like:  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });

Comment: thanks for the replies!, please read the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this (of curse with your data):

```
//Llamado al dos DatePicker
$("#txtFechaInicio").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: "17/09/2012",
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#txtFechaFin").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
$("#txtFechaFin").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: "17/09/2012",
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $("#txtFechaInicio").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: close.. but nop, i change the "dd/mm/yy" for "dd-mm-yy" and the datepicker set the date like year 2020

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reformat the date manually, you want to set a date for `minDate`, which can be done passing a date object instead, using the vars you made calculation:

```
$( "#salida" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(y, mm, dd) );
```

When you initialize datepicker you can add both `format`and `altFormat` which are display format and submit format respectively:

```
$( "#salida" ).datepicker({ altFormat: "dd/mm/yy", altFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
```

For further reading check [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate).

Comment: thanks but its too much for me, im still traying but cannot understand jquery, thanks!